# Should chemical compounds and elements be capitalized?

Tags: nomenclature

In the case of a name of a person, the first letter is written in capital letters.

- Should the first letter of name of a chemical compound or element be written in capital letters?

Comment: Related: [Why do people often capitalize element names?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/6381/7951)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The names of chemical compounds and elements should be capitalized if they appear at the beginning of a sentence or in a title - that is, they are treated just like any other common noun.

For example, a title:

> Why I Don't Like Zinc

or a sentence:

> Boron is my favorite element.

Within a sentence:

> We used boron and zinc in the experiment.
>
> Vinegar contains acetic acid.

The symbols for chemical elements are always capitalized, no matter what:

> We combined $\ce{As}$ and $\ce{W}$ to make a new alloy.

Comment: In the 1979 and 1993 IUPAC recommendations, example names were actually written with a capital initial letter. This was not necessarily wrong since most examples started on a new line. However, this practice has been abandoned in the 2013 recommendations in order to ensure that names of organic compounds are not considered as proper nouns.

Comment: Capitalising (some) words in a title is a matter of taste, not orthography.

Comment: @Karl That's like saying "Whether it's 'colour' or 'color' is a matter of taste, not spelling." Capitalization is _literally_ orthography: the way things are written down.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your point being?

Comment: @Karl My point being that your point is completely wrong.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have no idea what your first post had to do with mine, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Titles

Comment: @Karl You said that which words get capitalized in titles is not orthography. I am pointing out that this is incorrect: orthography is exactly the set of "rules" for how to write things down, including things like which letters get capitalized.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the diverse, incoherent and arbitrary "rules" by which some English speaking writers, editors, publishers uppercase first letters in titles, and others don't, is *not exactly* orthography. As opposed to rather widely recognised rulesets like "British English" or "American English" on general spelling.

Comment: Thank Todd Minehardt for your good answer, I just have a last complement question, What about substitutions on the nitrogen of an amide and similar cases of other types of substitutions? Should that atom be capitalized?

Comment: @Another.Chemist - Can you give a particular example?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt i.e. glucosamine (N-acetyl)-6-sulfatase

Comment: "N" is an element symbol, always uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

One addition to Todd's correct answer is that of trade names.  The canonical example of Teflon being capitalized,  the name being property of DuPont.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene

Although Teflon is not the chemical name,  the distinction is added to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: And complicated cases, such as acetylsalicylic acid, which is "Aspirin" in countries such as Canada, where [Beyer holds a trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin#Trademark), and "aspirin" in countries such as the US and UK, where the trademark lapsed and it's now considered to be a nonsystematic name.