Atomic radius decreasing across a Periodic Table row - does the RPD of an orbital change depending of the element considered?
I have a concern regarding the RPD of an orbital. Does the RPD of an orbital depend on the $Z$ (i.e. on the element under consideration) ? Especially, can the RPD of an orbital "shrink" to the left (i.e. $r_{mp}$ - most probable radius - is shifted to the left) as $Z$ increases ?
Let me introduce two examples:

Boron and carbon have the same occupied orbital ($2p$). However, the atomic radius is smaller for carbon than for boron. Does that mean that the RPD (and, hence, the $r_{mp}$) changes between the carbon and the boron (for the $2p$ orbital) ?
More complicated example: beryllium has the $2s$ occupied, and boron has the $2p$ occupied. Again, my question here is does the RPD of $2s$ "shrink" from beryllium to boron ? I ask about the $2s$ because the $2p$ seems to be out of interest here, since $r_{mp}$ of $2p$ is less than $r_{mp}$ of $2s$ (and I am supposing that it is the greatest $r_{mp}$ that controls the atomic radius) but please correct me if I'm wrong.


By RPD is probably meant the radial probability density. // Start with the wave functions for hydrogen-like atoms ( He^+, Li^2+ etc) and check they directly depend on the proton number.

@Poutnik thanks for your answer, so does this mean that the RPD of a fixed orbital "shrinks" to the left as $Z$ increases ?

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Non-relativistic_wavefunction_and_energy , in particular the exponential in $R_{nl}({\bf r})$. What do you think?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/should-chemical-compounds-and-elements-be-capitalized

Yes indeed. The Radial probability density (RPD) does change with atomic number Z and is shrinked as Z increases.
For a hydrogen-like atom the radial probability wave function is given as:-

Where-
r= radius,
n= principle quantum number,
l= azimuthal quantum number,
Z= atomic number,
aμ= Bohr radius,
L(2Zr/naμ)= Associated Laguerre polynomial
As Z increases the wave function gets compressed and closer to the nucleus.
However we must note that the above equation is valid for a hydrogen like species only where there is no inter electronic interactions. For multi electronic species, there still is dependence on Z, but the nature of this dependence is complex, as effects such as shielding, electron repulsions etc must be accounted for. The radial wave function will instead scale with effective nuclear charge.
I hope this answer helps!
